# Boot freeze when using second monitor (Xubuntu 16.04)?

Tags: boot, 16.04, xubuntu, multiple-monitors, freeze

I have Xubuntu 16.04 installed as the only OS on my Acer Aspire 5750 laptop. I have a BenQ external monitor connected such that I have a dual monitor setup (my laptop screen + BenQ).

When the BenQ monitor, connected to my laptop via HDMI, is not receiving a signal (which happens when the computer is off), it displays a message "HDMI No Cable Connected!" and presumably goes into some idle mode. When it is in this mode and I turn on the computer, the boot hangs and I see the Acer logo covered partially by a black rectangle's silhouette:

[image]

I set GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="" in /etc/default/grub to attempt to see the boot messages, but nothing can be seen - the computer really freezes at boot. If I proceed by turning off the computer forcibly (hold the power button for 5 seconds) and quickly turn it back on again, which avoids the BenQ monitor from going into its idle mode and the boot sequence proceeds successfully. If I unplug the monitor and use my laptop's screen only, boot works nominally.

My question: what can I do to fix this boot freeze? Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Just FYI, this post might get duped to http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it so you might want to check that out, so that if it didn't fix it, you can mention that you tried it, so it won't get wrongly duped.

Comment: None of the link's fixes work for me unfortunately. My problem is a true "freeze" - when I have the HDMI external monitor connected when I press the power button, all I get is a frozen part-covered Acer logo as shown in the picture. Grub, etc. nothing can be accessed with any sort of key combo.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Xubuntu 16.04 on my old Acer Aspire notebook. Once installed, on reboot, I get the login screen, enter my correct password, the password dialog disappears, leaving wallpaper, and thats all -- never finishes activating the desktop. I have spent hours trying to find a work-around, with no luck. Here's what finally worked for me:

If I raise the laptop lid and then shut it, the desktop appears.

Next:
-- select main menu.
-- select 'settings'
-- select 'display'.

It showed my external HP display selected as #2, followed by the Laptop (disabled).

There is a drop down which showed Laptop as the first option. Underneath, a check box for 'Use this display' (unchecked), and next, a check box for 'Primary display' (unchecked).

I used the drop down to select my monitor (which was listed after 'laptop'), which showed my monitor along with the correct settings. I checked both:
'Use this display' and 'Primary display'.

After rebooting, I logged in, and the desktop came up right away on the external monitor. I can only hope the open-shut laptop lid/screen thing works for you.

If not, and someone can fill in where the configuration file for the displays can be found in your home directory, you could do a control-alt-T, and use the terminal to edit the config file, and I suspect that would work.

I'm guessing the trick is to positively assert the external monitor as 'primary'.